# Delete Apps from iOS Simulator using terminal

Tags: bash, unix, terminal

Im trying to delete apps from the iOS Simulator using this script running on our Build Server

```
#!/bin/Bash

#Go to iOS Sim
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator

#Loop through each Version of iOS
for dir in ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/*/
do
    dir=${dir%*/}
    cd "$dir"

    #Check if the iOS version has any apps installed                    
    if [ -d "$dir/Applications" ]; then
        echo Applications folder exists in "$dir"
        cd "$dir/Applications"

        #Delete each app
        for app in "$dir/Application/*/"
        do
            echo $app

            if [ "${#app}" -eq 36 ]; then   
                echo Delete Folder
            fi
        done

    fi
done
```

Im stuck at the `#Delete each` app section. I want to loop through the Applications folder and first check if the Folder's number of characters is 36(GUID) then delete the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `*` in quotes, bash will interpret it literally, and not as a glob. You could change the for to this:

```
 for app in "$dir"/Application/*/
```

Of course you have already entered the directory, so

```
for app in */
```

is probably what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I'm all about using the numerous (and awesome) utilities you have at hand for this sort of thing. You can use something like

```
LENGTH=`echo $app | wc -c`
if [[ $LENGTH -eq 36 ]]; then
  # do the thing
fi
```

Note: The magic here is the use of back ticks and the wc (wordcount) utility. While you're looking at the man page for wc, checkout tr also (only partially related, but another excellent tool to knw).

Comment: If you want to measure the length of the string like this you should use echo's `-n` option, otherwise you will count the newline as well (and quote the "$app" variables - in case it has consecutive spaces). But the expression `"${#app}"` also gives the length, OP's problem is somewhere else.